# Why are only column names appearing in the association rules instead of column values?

Tags: r, apriori

Here is a snippet of my dataset:

[image]

There are 26 columns  and about 5000 rows totally with some NA values

```
r<-apriori(data,parameter = list(supp=0.9,conf=0.6,minlen=2))
```

### Output

```
lhs                 rhs          support     confidence  lift     count

[1] {Product.13=} => {Product.14=} 0.9061887 1.0000000  1.077855 5081    
[2] {Product.14=} => {Product.13=} 0.9061887 0.9767397  1.077855 5081   
[3] {Product.13=} => {Product.15=} 0.9061887 1.0000000  1.059124 5081   
[4] {Product.15=} => {Product.13=} 0.9061887 0.9597658  1.059124 5081   
[5] {Product.13=} => {Product.16=} 0.9061887 1.0000000  1.044718 5081
```

Desired output format
    `{Cranberries} => {Strawberries}`
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ! Can you provide with the dataSet to see how have you treated it ?

Comment: How do you have imported your data?

Comment: These rules are intuitively correct!  If Product.13 is blank, then Product.14 is blank 100% of the time. Etc.